# Crop background image and scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

I want to display a cropped background image and then scale it and have the same part of the image show.

I know the pixel value for background offset, but as soon as I begin animating the background size, the background becomes offset. I think it would fix the problem if I calculated the pixel value into a percentage value, but I have no idea how to do that due to the strange nature of percentage background positions: http://www.sitepoint.com/css-using-percentages-in-background-image/

If I animate the background position it works, but the result is jittery.

This gives a result similar to what I want, but jittery:

```
zc.css("background-position", offset + "px 0");
zc.animate({"background-position": offset * 2, top: 100%, bottom: 100%, left: 100%, right: 100%}, {duration: 500, queue: false, easing: "easeOutCubic"});
```

Comment: You might be able to use the [background-size attribute](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) and/or the [css transform: scale](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/)

Comment: You should post the code you've attempted that isn't working exactly how you'd like.